# How to get the html text that is displayed on the screen with webview_flutter?

Tags: flutter, web-scraping, webview-flutter

with FLUTTER :)

I would like to retrieve the text that is displayed on the screen when I load a page on a website in order to be able to analyze it

I would like to be able to do it with webview_futter (or an equivalent) because the website I want to check ask to enter username and password (only the first time)

Does someone here know how to do it and have time to help me  ?

Thank's a lot for your help

Pierre

Comment: Hello Sir, I think the topic you should be looking into is web scrapping. An example in flutter would be https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-scraping-in-flutter/amp/

Comment: Thank's a lot but I already have test this example but it do not work in my case because I need to connect one time on the website using webview_futter to authentificate ( user name + password + securitty) and after having make it one time I can have access to the page I want to scrapp because I have got cookies from the website
This is the reason why I would like to use webview_futter (or an equivalent)

Comment: I understand. If login can be done by the user something like this should work? https://www.appsloveworld.com/flutter/100/48/flutter-scraping-a-site-with-javascript-generated-content-without-darthtml / https://gist.github.com/fredriccliver/97f98965d765107086ea045ee7c7909b

Comment: could you post again your link complete because the link here does not work unfortunatly

Comment: Minor nit.  "scrapping" is "to scrap", like discard.  "scraping" is "to scrape" like extract information from.  I chuckle at "web scrapping" as in, throw the web away. :)